# telnet server not executing commands

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, telnet

I am connected in a telnet session in linux environment, but when I type commands and press enter, nothing happens. The TCP connection is in established state and when I checked the packets, the server is just echoing back whatever I typed and not taking any action.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you using telnet and not SSH?

Comment: Check your terminal settings. They are most likely wrong. Also it would help if you gave more info like what OS to/from, what telnet client, etc.

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman The session is in an isolated environment, not connected to internet; session is for testing purposes.

Comment: @Jake Regardless of whether it's an isolated environment, telnet is highly deprecated and you're losing out on all the useful features of SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To which port is your telnet session connected?  If it's not port 23, you might just be connected to the echo service or something which is designed to do what you're seeing.

Otherwise, try pressing the break sequence (normally Control-], you may need to press return afterward) and do

```
send ayt
```

That should get an affirmative response if telnetd is working.   You can try some other things (type "help" at the telnet> prompt to get some ideas).

If the telnet session seems to be working, what application software do you think you're connected to?    Is that software working?

If you have access to the remote machine via some other mechanism, try investigating from that end (for example running strace on the user process your session is connected to).   Failing that, ask the administrator of the remote machine.

Last, why on Earth are you still using telnet?   Did you supply a password to log in?   If yes, your password is in danger of being eavesdropped.   You should almost certainly use ssh instead.